# fastapi mongodb how to add pagination and limit number of items per page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, fastapi

I am using pymongo. `Category.city_collection.find()` getting all collection of result. But I want to show only 5 result per page. I tried this `Category.city_collection.find().limit(5)` which showing 5 result on first page but how to go others page like second page, third page etc? I am using mongo db with my fastapi project. here is my full code

```
@router.get('/all_city')
async def all_city():
   
      all_category = Category.city_collection.find() 
      category = convert_json(all_category)
      return category
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `skip` and `limit`

With [skip](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/), you set the number of documents that you will skip.

With [limit](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/), you set the page size.

**Example:**

```
db.test.find({}).skip(10).limit(10)
```

Would return the 2nd page in 10 document page sizes.

A `skip(20).limit(10)`, would return the 3rd page...

Most of the times you should use this methods over ordered data.